# Migrations are automatically added in production DB despite AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false

Tags: entity-framework

I have until recently been using Automatic Migrations using Entity Framework code first even in production environment in my MVC web project. The project is small and I have been aware of pros and cons using automatic migrations. This has however not been a problem until now.

After the latest migration which only added a couple of columns I noticed that after a while I got errors on the website. After checking I noticed that the added columns were gone and I had verified that they were in place earlier. I then checked the __MigrationHistory and noticed hundreds of rows called "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_AutomaticMigration". I realized that the changes I did were after a while removed using the Down part of the migration. The rows in MigrationHistory had started adding up before this migration but I am not aware of what was changed in those AutomaticMigrations because it was nothing I noticed. Even stranger was that a short while later another AutomaticMigration was added which added those columns again. So it seems it keeps running the same migration over and over adding/removing the migration.

After being unable to fix the problem I decided to leave automatic migrations so I set

`AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;`

I am also using MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion on the initializer if that is information that is relevant.

I then removed all AutomaticMigration rows in __MigrationHistory (I have always created named migrations for all changes). Created a script using *update-database -script* for the migration that caused problem. Updated the code on the server with this build and ran the script. Still I am getting this behaviour. The migration is removed in an AutomaticMigration despite that the code is set not to run automatic migrations.

I have tried to restart the site and app pool and done an iisreset /restart to see if there was something cached but no luck. I cannot get rid of the automatic migration problem.

I now noticed that after the AutomaticMigration was added (and my changes were removed from the db) I saw exceptions being logged from hangfire which runs scheduled jobs that the DB Context could not be created due to pending migrations. But if I change reset back to the state which I expect it runs fine and no complains about pending migrations.

I have run out of ideas of what to try and I can't figure out why this is happening so any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Never mind. Stupid mistake... I completely forgot that another application was using the same database and I had not updated that application not to use automatic migrations so basically the two applications were in a race to add/remove the change I had made in the model.